# Demand form for multi team discipline

Tags: forms, power-automate, ms-forms

I'm currently developing a demand form in Microsoft Forms and utilizing Power Automate to automate subsequent actions.

I'm seeking a method to implement an initial step where the requester can choose the specific team to which they're directing their request. Subsequently, a tailored form would be presented based on their selection.

Using a single form for the entire directorate lacks specificity for the various types of work potentially being requested.

I've attempted to create a comprehensive form within Microsoft Forms, but encountered challenges.

Thank you.